# Trying to use the output of Grep -E in if statement in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, redhat

I am trying to use the output of $mount to check whether there are network mount points and if so, do what is stated. Instead, I keep getting the else statement no matter what I try.

If I run `mount | egrep 'cifs|nfs|rpc'` on command line, I see that there are network mounts.  How do I do this in a script?  I CANNOT figure it out after much trial and error and want to pull my hair out.

Red Hat 6.8 is my OS but will need it to work for 6.x and 7.x

Sample output when run at command line:

```
~# mount | egrep 'cifs|nfs|rpc' 

sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
machine.example.com:/export/home/x/ICD103 on
/mnt/ICD103 type nfs(rw,soft,int,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,sloppy,vers=4,addr=xx.xxx.xxx.xx,clientaddr=10.xxx.xxx.xxx)
//new-devstore/Stable/Assets on /mnt/assets type cifs (rw)
```

```
mount=$(mount | egrep 'cifs|nfs|rpc')

if $mount; then
    mount > $destBAK/mount.txt;
    cp -p /etc/auto.cifs > $destBAK 2>/dev/null;
    cp -p /etc/auto.master > $destBAK 2>/dev/null;
    cp -p /root/.smbauth > $destBAK 2>/dev/null;
    cp -p /etc/fstab > $destBAK 2>/dev/null;
else
    echo "No Network Mount"
fi
```

Output after running ./backup.sh

```
~# ./backup.sh
Making backup directory /tmp/BAK_2017-10-13 now 
Copying files to /tmp/BAK_2017-10-13
./backup.sh: line 34: sunrpc: command not found
No Network Mount
```

Comment: What do you want `if $mount` to do? If you want it to check whether the variable `$mount` is empty, then that's `if [[ $mount ]]`. As it is, it's taking the contents of the variable `$mount`, splitting it into words, and running those words as a command. The command doesn't exist, so you get "command not found".

Comment: you are currently running whatever is in $mount as a command to be checked by if.

Comment: Probably simpler just to check if `egrep` found anything.  That is `if mount | egrep -q 'cifs|nfs|rpc'; then ...`

Comment: I want it to perform the statements after "then" if egrep finds what im asking it to look for.  I just dont know how to do that.

Comment: The `-q` option does that.

Comment: -q results in this output:

./backup.sh
Making backup directory /tmp/BAK_2017-10-13 now
Copying files to /tmp/BAK_2017-10-13
./backup.sh: line 36: /tmp/BAK_2017-10-13: Is a directory
./backup.sh: line 37: /tmp/BAK_2017-10-13: Is a directory
./backup.sh: line 38: /tmp/BAK_2017-10-13: Is a directory
./backup.sh: line 39: /tmp/BAK_2017-10-13: Is a directory

Comment: do you really want output redirection to $destBAK? Shouldn't all those `>`'s just not be there?

Comment: right Paul, the >'s should not be there with a copy command

Comment: To be more clear on how to use `-q`: `if mount | egrep -q 'cifs|whatever'; then ...`; there's no point to a `$mount` variable at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying

```
if $mount
```

will try to execute the value of $mount. It's basically like saying

```
if "foo"; then echo ok; else echo no; fi
```

Unless your string has a successfully executable value, it will always throw an error and give you the `else`.

Why assigning to a var?

```
if mount | egrep 'cifs|nfs|rpc'
then ...
```

will use the return from the egrep.

If you *do* need to catch and save the output collectively, then use

```
if [[ -n "$mount" ]] # tests string for nonzero length
then ...
```

If you need the output lines individually, try

```
hit=0
mount | egrep 'cifs|nfs|rpc' |
  while read mnt
  do hit=1
     # ... all your mount code above
  done
if (( hit )) # math evaluation
then : any remaining stuff you might need to do
else echo "No Network Mount"
fi
```

> update --

an attempt to re-engineer what you want:

```
tmp=/tmp/mount.txt
mount > $tmp
if egrep -q 'cifs|nfs|rpc' $tmp
then mv $tmp $destBAK
     cp -p /etc/auto.cifs $destBAK
     cp -p /etc/auto.master $destBAK
     cp -p /root/.smbauth $destBAK
     cp -p /etc/fstab $destBAK
else
    echo "No Network Mount"
    rm $tmp
fi
```

This should work. I took off all the stderr redirections because you should know about errors, and ideally handle them, but at least here it will report them.

This doesn't work for you?

Comment: I assigned it to a var because trying it  "if mount | egrep -q 'cifs|nfs|rpc'; " doesn't work.

I just need to know if 'cifs|nfs|rpc' is there and if so, do the commands below

Comment: I tried your code above to ouput individual lines but that gives same results.

basically I want to run mount command, if cifs, nfs, or rpc is present in the output, i then want to copy the files to my backup destination $destBAK, but everything i've tried goes to the else statement.

Comment: OK, so it was the >'s that were messing the whole thing up. I apologize.  After trying

    if mount | egrep 'cifs|nfs|rpc'
then ...

it works now.  Thank you!

I originally had it as cat /etc/auto.cifs > $destBAK

Answer (score 0):

it is because of the redirection in your code.
use double 'greater than' signs, >>, this will append instead of overwrite each cp statement in your code. Something like this should work:

```
if $mount; then
    mount > $destBAK/mount.txt;
    cp -p /etc/auto.cifs >> $destBAK 2>/dev/null;
    cp -p /etc/auto.master >> $destBAK 2>/dev/null;
    cp -p /root/.smbauth >> $destBAK 2>/dev/null;
    cp -p /etc/fstab >> $destBAK 2>/dev/null;
else
    echo "No Network Mount"
fi
```

Comment: sorry, $destBAK is a directory

Comment: This still isn't usefully valid syntax, is it? The cp should fail with only one arg, and you can't usefully write/append to a directory this way. (Thus the reason not to throw away your stderr)